# in C#, How to post a user message to an Windows and process it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, postmessage

In C++ on Windows, we use user defined message to in form UI to update data thru PostMessage API. We can use PostMessage in C# but do not know how to process user defined message in Forms!
Some ones will tell me to use delegated and invoke but we have problems when forms closed or not already created when threads call delegated. We still prefer PostMessage to inform UI to update data.
Please Help.

Comment: I don't understand what this means. What are "user defined message in Forms"? If `PostMessage` works for you, why not simply use it? And why would you expect that `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` would work properly to send messages to things that haven't been created yet or have already been destroyed? `PostMessage` doesn't work for that either.

Comment: Hi Cody Gray, "user defined message" means WM_USER in C++. In C++, We defined message like #define WM_UPDATE_TRANSACTION_STATUS WM_USER + 1. You misunderstood, We got exceptions many times when threads Invoke delegates in closed or not ready forms. We think that PostMessage will solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form` has a method you can override, [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc.aspx), that will receive your custom message. It takes a `Message` structure as its parameter, which encapsulates the hwnd, msg, wParam, and lParam parameters of the message, and includes a field for the message result. So assuming you have a registered message:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    const int MyMessage = WM_USER + 0x05; // for example

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == MyMessage)
        {
            // do whatever with your message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew Ferreira, how to send a C# class in PostMessage?

Comment: You mean the entire object graph of a class, serialized? Don't do that. Use your custom message to instruct your application to open a pipe (or another IPC mechanism) and send the serialized class that way.